# Maximum likelihood estimation of a gamma distribution mixed with linear regression in R

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, gamma-distribution, interval-censoring

I have this excercise in R and I don't know where to start. The income dataset was collected with intervals instead of the actual number. The following table shows every interval in the dataset.

| $y_i$ | Interval |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | $850 \leq z_i \leq 999$ |
| 2 | $1000 \leq z_i \leq 2000$ |
| 3 | $2001 \leq z_i \leq 3000$ |
| 4 | $3001 \leq z_i \leq 4000$ |
| 5 | $4001 \leq z_i \leq 5000$ |
| 6 | $5001 \leq z_i \leq 10000$ |

The proposed regression model for the income is:

$z_i \sim Gamma(\phi,\frac{\phi}{\mu_i})$

$\mu_i = exp(\beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \beta_2w_i)$

We also know that the maximum likelihood function for this model can be written like:

$$f(Y|\theta) = \prod [F(U_i|\mu_i,\phi) - F(L_i|\mu_i,\phi)]$$

Where $U_i$ and $L_i$ are the upper bound and lower bound of the income and $F$ is the cumulative gamma distribution with parameters $\mu_i$ and $\phi$

**Question: Estimate via ML and compute the 95% confidence interval for all the parameters.** For the inital values of the parameters I'm using the betas from the linear model of the log of the middle point of the interval against $x_i$ and $w_i$ as the professor suggested.

$x_i$: experience in years

$w_i$: gender variable (1 for woman, 0 for man)

The algorithms used in class to optimize the log likelihood function are **optim** or **nlminb**.

The data

````r
freq <- c(1,1,1,2,4,6,18,39,4,3,7,9,
4,9,24,3,3,2,1,4,18,24,1,3,8,6,6,
12,27,1,3,7,12,1,3,11,32,1,3,8,15,17,76,4,4,16,7,
1,2,3,7,33,1,5,5,1,9,26,1,7,3,12,28,2,3,4,
9,4,12,27,1,3,2,9,3,9,6,12,4,1,11,5,2,2,
1,3,20,56,3,7,6,1,5,18,1,3,4,9,23,3,5,2,4,22,5,3,
3,19,1,2,6,8,3,16,69,2,5,5,1,2,10,27,2,5,
3,7,29,1,8,3,3,12,36,2,4,5,3,5,18,1,1,5,5,3,
9,21,19,9,1,1,8,9,13,7,1,8,17,63,2,2,6,1,1,2,6,
9,1,2,1,1,1,14,2,3,5,1,3,6,19,1,1,1,
5,20,2,5,1,1,2,3,29,1,4,2,6,1,3,6,2,4,1,
3,6,13,21,13,1,7,7,12,4,2,1,4,1,1,1,
3,1,2,1,1,1,6,1,2,3,19,20,15,1,3,6,
23,5,1,1,2,1,9,13,14,2,3,8,9,3,12,16,
20,3,6,8,8,3,2,8,14,28,2,5,15,5,2,4,8,20,2,4,7,5)

tmp_experience <- c(
 1,1,1,1,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,
 12,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,
 15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,17,17,17,17,17,18,18,18,18,18,
 18,18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,20,
 20,20,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,
 23,24,24,24,24,24,24,25,25,25,25,25,25,26,26,26,26,26,26,27,
 27,27,27,27,27,28,28,28,28,28,28,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,
 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,31,
 31,31,31,31,31,31,31,32,32,32,32,32,32,33,33,33,33,33,
 34,34,34,34,34,34,34,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,37,
 37,38,38,38,39,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,40,40,40,40,
 41,42,42,42,43,44,45,45,45,46,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,
 5,50,51,55,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
 7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9)

tmp_gender <- c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,
 0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,
 0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,
 1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,
 0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,
 1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,
 0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,
 1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
 1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
 1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,
 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
 0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,
 1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1
)

tmp_interval <- c(3,4,5,5,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,5,6,4,5,6,2,4,5,
 6,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,4,
 5,6,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,4,
 6,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,
 2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,3,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,5,6,5,6,4,5,6,
 5,6,5,6,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,5,6,4,5,6,3,
 5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,2,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,1,
 2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,4,
 5,6,4,5,6,2,4,5,6,6,3,4,5,6,3,5,6,3,4,5,
 6,4,6,5,6,5,5,6,5,6,4,6,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,
 6,3,5,6,5,6,5,6,5,6,6,3,5,6,6,2,3,4,5,6,
 2,3,4,5,6,6,4,6,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,3,
 4,5,6,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6)


interval <- c() # income interval
experience <- c() # experience in years
gender <- c() # gender, 1 for woman, 0 for man


for(i in 1:271){
 experience <- c(experience,rep(tmp_experience[i],freq[i]))
 gender <- c(gender,rep(tmp_gender[i],freq[i]))
 interval <- c(interval,rep(tmp_interval[i],freq[i]))
}

income <- data.frame(experience,gender,interval)
income$L <- ifelse(income$interval == 1,850,
                  ifelse(income$interval == 2,1000,
                      ifelse(income$interval == 3, 2001,
                                ifelse(income$interval == 4,3001,
                                    ifelse(income$interval == 5,4001,5000)))))

income$U <- ifelse(income$interval == 1,999,
                  ifelse(income$interval == 2,2000,
                      ifelse(income$interval == 3, 3000,
                                ifelse(income$interval == 4,4000,
                                    ifelse(income$interval == 5,5000,10000)))))

income$M <- (income$U+income$L)/2

linearModel <- lm(log(M) ~ x + factor(w), data = income)
mu <- exp(linearModel$fitted.values)

# Initial values for the parameters
b0 <- linearModel$coefficients[1]
b1 <- linearModel$coefficients[2]
b2 <- linearModel$coefficients[3]

```
````

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: You have interval censored data, search this site for (maximum) likelihood and interval censoring!